# Porting JavaScript escape() to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, porting

I need to escape entire javascript code block using `escape()` compatible function via PHP, and then put resulting JavaScript code back into a code construct like this:

```
document.write(unescape(ESCAPED_JS));
```

I'm not trying to increase security by doing this, protect code, or anything like that. Just to make it a bit harder to glance over a code and see what it does.

Does anyone have a working solution for this, or idea how to do it? The only reference I found about it is on [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#79595), but it only deals with unescaping JS-escaped string using PHP, but by taking special care of UTF-8 characters (which I also need to consider).

Comment: `escape()` and `unescape()` do not work with non-ascii characters.  My advice would be to forget about it, obfuscation will only encourage some people further.

Comment: On a side note, you may want to check out the YUI Compressor (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/). It will replace variables names with single letters (where possible) and strip out any unnecessary white space. Not only does it make a script very hard to read, but it also reduces the size, which decreases page load times.

Comment: @Brendan: that's most likely what I'll do - compress code, because loading time is actually more important than readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`escape` is not a standard function. Better use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) or JSON instead.

Comment: Well, if it's not standard function, then there's no need to port it anywhere. Thanks. I'll use some JS compressor to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Gumbo is right (as always), but I think `rawurlencode` and `rawurldecode` are the php equivalents of js `escape` and `unescape`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use urlencode and urldecode to do this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: ... and the Javascript counterpart?

Comment: I'm unable to do it using (raw)urlencode/decode functions, because they only encode special characters.